# SQL - Split a column into two columns in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table. Considering the id starts from 0.

Table 1

```
ID     Letter
1        A
2        B
3        C
4        D
6        E
```

I need following output

```
Col1     Col2
NULL      A
B         C
D         NULL
E         NULL
```

I tried using union with id, id - 1 and id + 1, but I couldn't figure out how to get letter based on ids, also tried even odd logic but nothing worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please format the tables so that the rows and columns are clearer?

Comment: please tell us which DBMS are you using ...

Comment: Sorry, I was just formatting the tables only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't post the database engine, so I'll assume PostgreSQL where the modulus operand is `%`.

The query should be:

```
select o.letter, e.letter
  from (
    select id, letter, id as base from my_table where id % 2 = 0
  ) o full outer join (
    select id, letter, (id - 1) as base from my_table where id % 2 <> 0
  ) e on e.base = o.base
  order by coalesce(o.base, e.base)
```

Please take the following option with a grain of salt since I don't have a way of testing it in MySQL 5.6. In the absence of a full outer join, you can perform two outer joins, and then you can union them, as in:

```
select * from (
  select o.base, o.letter, e.letter
    from (
      select id, letter, id as base from my_table where id % 2 = 0
    ) o left join (
      select id, letter, (id - 1) as base from my_table where id % 2 <> 0
    ) e on e.base = o.base
  union
  select e.base, o.letter, e.letter
    from (
      select id, letter, id as base from my_table where id % 2 = 0
    ) o right join (
      select id, letter, (id - 1) as base from my_table where id % 2 <> 0
    ) e on e.base = o.base
) x
order by base
```

Comment: Well, that certainly gets the job done, despite scant details from OP. Well done. :)

Comment: Thank you for quick response with so less details. The logic works fine but it's MySQL and full outer join wouldn't work.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: MySQL 5.6. Also I tried using left and right join then union but don't know how to proceed further

Comment: Please take a look at the second SQL. I hope it works, but it becomes increasingly uglier.

Comment: thank you so much! I will test and let you know whether it worked! Thanks a ton for your help

Answer (score 3):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when id % 2 = 0 then letter end) as col1,
       max(case when id % 2 = 1 then letter end) as col2
from t
group by floor(id / 2);
```

If you prefer, you can use `mod()` instead of `%`.  MySQL supports both.

Comment: Going to suggest an edit to correct a minor typo: `floor(i / 2)` should be `floor(id / 2)` if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: I have to say, using `max()` and `group by floor(n / 2)` is really clever - I'd never seen that used before.  How did you come up with that?  Had you already seen that somewhere else?

Comment: @dossy . . . No doubt, I've seen similar problems.  The solution is more obvious to me than a `join` based solution.  The problem "looks" like conditional aggregation to me.